# Referencing a previous used Class in a Intellij Live Template

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm currently developing Android applications on Android

I was getting tired of writing `SomeView view = (SomeView) findViewById(R.id.view_name);` over and over again and decided to try and write a template for it.

I discovered Live Templates and decided to try and write on for this code snippet. I've managed to write the following:

```java
= ($CLASS_NAME$) findViewById(R.id.$END$);
```

This will start the cursor at `$CLASS_NAME$` and jump it to `$END$` when I press Tab.

Which is nice but I'd like it to insert the first class name it finds, working backwards, and insert that into `$CLASS_NAME$`. Thus writing `SomeView view` and then calling the template would insert `SomeView` at `$CLASS_NAME$`.

I realise that the solution, if there is one, is probably to write a custom expression for the variable but I just don't know how to go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' think you easily make a backward reference, but you can try someting like this:

```
$CLASS_NAME$ $END$ = ($CLASS_NAME$) findViewById(R.id.$END$);
```

or

```
$CLASS_NAME$ $VAR$ = ($CLASS_NAME$) findViewById(R.id.$END$);
```

Comment: That is, in fact, a much cleaner solution than what I had in mind. Cheers!